# Contact form 7 adding an image to the email body

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to add some images to the email body that gets sent to the users email (not as attachments) but when they arrive via the email they are broken and do not show.

I have tried using:

```
<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage.jpeg">
<img src="wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage.jpeg">
<img src="uploads/2019/11/myimage.jpeg">
```

But nothing works, I thought it would be as easy as adding an image as you do via html but it doesnt seems to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: where do you want to add an image?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the email as an HTML doc or are you just putting HTML text into the email doc?

Your email service might be reading your code incorrectly, thinking it's just text being sent in an email document.

Do some troubleshooting. Can other HTML elements (like headings and [hyperlinks](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp)) appear in your email? If not, it's an email problem and not one with your code.

That being said, the 2nd and 3rd links are not viewable via a browser - it looks like they are pulling from your system as opposed to being an online link. That might be part of the problem as well.